# datatemplate binding wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, datatemplate

i'v a `list box`, which contains one `listboxitem` & this `listboxitem` contains a `wrap panel`, in which i want to add `grids` (containing user profile pics & names)
so that i'd created a `datatemplate`--->

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserGridListTemplate">
            <Grid Height="140" Width="155">
                <Grid.Background>   
                      <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding UPicPath}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding UName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="27" OpacityMask="#7C000000" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and i want to assign the data(image sources & texblock values) dynamically in c#, 
So how can i access this `datatemplate` & his child controls(`image` & `textblock`) in code and as well as how could this `datatemplate` to be added to that `listboxitem` ,

for an idea that generated xaml how will be look like--->

```
<Grid Grid.RowSpan="5" Width="334" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="134,80,-12,20">
                        <ListBox>
                            <ListBoxItem>
                                <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                          //   -->UserGridListTemplate instance 1 with some data assigned
                          //   -->UserGridListTemplate instance 1 with some data assigned
                          //   -->UserGridListTemplate instance 1 with some data assigned
                             and so on................ 

                                </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
```

something look like above

Comment: Where are the "user profile pics & names" coming from? Are they in a collection somewhere?

Comment: @Silver Solver : well these are coming from database, however my ques is how to add controls(with given datatemplate) in c#, doesn't maters from whr data is coming ???